# Should I harden Commerce Engine ApiSecret?

Tags: sitecore-commerce, identity-server

The default Commerce Engine implementation has a hard-coded Identity Server Api name & secret:

```
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.Authority = this.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:SitecoreIdentityServerUrl").Value;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.EnableCaching = false;
    options.ApiName = "EngineAPI";
    options.ApiSecret = "secret";
});
```

Should I change the `ApiSecret` to a more secure string for production usage?

Comment: will your identity server be available publicly?

Comment: Only internally, but still, some security is required.

Comment: you can change to something more secured but you also need to change same in identity server configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the `ApiSecret` is actually unused as the Commerce Engine uses JWT and *not* Reference tokens. See Identity Server documentation: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/apis.html#supporting-reference-tokens

One could change the code to:

```
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.Authority = this.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:SitecoreIdentityServerUrl").Value;
    options.ApiName = "EngineAPI";
});
```

NB. As the Identity Server by default uses RSA encryption it uses the [JSON Web Keyset](https://auth0.com/docs/jwks) (available at e.g. https://identity/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks) to verify the JWT.